# Mongoid. undefined method exception when using aggregation framework features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB shell command which works fine. The command is:

```
db.sessions.aggregate({$unwind: "$Sessions List"}, 
{$match: { "Sessions List.Parent Session":"My Session"}}, 
{$group:{_id:"$Sessions List.Parent Session", avg_val:{$avg:"$Sessions List.Length"}}})
```

result is: "result" :

```
[{
   "_id" : "My Session",
   "avg_val" : 8.846666666666666
}],
"ok" : 1
```

but when trying to run it through Mongoid (using latest available Mongoid, Origin, Moped) it fails with NoMethodError `(undefined method` __ bson_load__' for nil:NilClass)` exception.

Ruby code is the following:

```
Session.collection.aggregate({
'$unwind' => '$Sessions List',
'$match' => { 'Sessions List.Parent Session' => 'My Session'},
'$group' => {
'_id' => '$Sessions List.Parent Session',
'avg_val' => {
'$avg' => '$Sessions List.Length'
}}});
```